# Network ARP poisoned with Cain but Fiddler not modifying HTML.

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing

**The Situation**

I have successfully used Cain to ARP poison my phone and traffic is being routed via my PC. I have confirmed this in Wireshark and Cain is also able to recover passwords for my SMTP and POP email accounts.

**The Problem**

I have setup Fiddler and using a Fiddler Script I'm trying to do some basic HTML injection/modification by modifying a news headline on the BBC News website.

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {

    if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }

    if(oSession.HostnameIs("www.bbc.co.uk/news/")) {
        oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
        var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
        oBody = oBody.replace("US and UK pull staff out of Yemen", 
                              "Hello World!");
        oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
    }   
}
```

**The Question**
Fiddler is working on my own browser traffic, navigating to the BBC News website shows me the headline Hello World! My question is should it work on the traffic being routed through my NIC by Cain? Navigating to the same page on my phone does not show the manipulated headline.

Comment: i have no experience with "Fiddler" but this might help you to achive what you want [ettercap MITM & packet injection](http://ronnieflip.blogspot.de/2010/10/ettercap-mitm-browser-injection-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, Fiddler is only supposed to work on local browser traffic. You need another type of program, a http proxy ([like](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/upside-down-ternet.html) [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) to do what you intend.